# Showing content of pushpin when tapped - Windows Phone 7

Tags: database, silverlight, windows-phone-7, dictionary, pushpin

I'm having some trouble understanding pushpins and their content, since there are many articles using a single pushpin.

I obtained data from a database and have close to 1000 pushpins on the map, but I don't like that they show the content.

What I want is the pushpins to look without letters, for example, just look like a black figure, but if I tap on them they show their content (That is simply an address). Same goes when I tap on the map, I hope their content to be Visible.Collapsed.

I want it to look more like iOS-ish, maybe not with an actual pushpin figure, but without the content showing up, since it looks ugly when it doesn't let you read other pushpins content.

Can you help me out? Or point me in the right direction? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is what you are looking for [custom bing map pushpin](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Pushpin-Custom-Tooltip-Different-Techniques)

you had to subscribe to the MapControl Tap event and Pushpin Tap event.

the pushpin tap event allow you to only show their content when you tapped on the individual pushpin.

while the mapcontrol tap event allow you to collapse the shown content of the pushpin.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me if the content of my pushpins are different from each other.

Comment: you need to make use of the tag property of the pushpin when you are adding the pushpin to the map.
e.g
pushpin.Tag = "<Insert content here">;